# Dynamic parameter in jQuery Ajaxt tab url?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a set of jQuery Ajax tabs which need to be opened using a dynamic parameter, defined in a global Javascript variable.

So far I have this:

```
function getVariable() {
    return globalVar;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            data: {dynamicParameter: getVariable()}
        }
    });
});

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="firstTab.html" title="first">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="secondTab.html" title="second">Second</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I click on each of the tabs, request is generated as "firstTab.html?dynamicParameter=someValue".

The problem is, as globalVar value changes, my requests do not, they remain exactly the same as with initial load. Is there a way I can get them to reflect the changes from my variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that the ajaxOptions are set on init of the tab. You should do something like this to override the data propertie.

you can use the `select` callback to overide the `ajaxOptions`

(haven't tested this)

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function() {
        $(this).tabs("option", { ajaxOptions: { data: { dynamicParameter: getVariable() } } });
    },
    ajaxOptions: {
        data: {dynamicParameter: getVariable()}
    }
});
```

Comment: I got this just after I posted the question :)

Is there a way I can both serialize data from a form AND add a parameter as well, at the same time?

Comment: sure you can. `var data = $('form').serializeArray();
data.push({name: 'varName', value: 'varValue'});`

Comment: Great, thanks! Is there a simple way to update the value of an existing element in an array?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the brackets '()'

```
{dynamicParameter: getVariable()}
```

to

```
{dynamicParameter: getVariable}
```

that way you will pass the function, not the value.
and when it is called it will ask for the new value.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the code supplied in the answer above used to work for me in 1.9, but after upgrading to jquery 1.10 I found it no longer worked. I also found the a post on the jquery site explaining  the change and the new way to accomplish this; so, I thought I would share

**OLD WAY:**

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    ajaxOptions: {
        username: "foo",
        password: "bar"
    }
});
```

**NEW WAY:**

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.ajaxSettings.username = "foo";
        ui.ajaxSettings.password = "bar";
    }
});
```

**It may be that this no longer work either**; however as I later found this second link. Which seems to imply that the only way to pass data is now in the beforeSend method using the `ui.ajaxSettings.url` property. This of course limits you to get requests. I wish they had left this functionality alone.

Here is a link to the post [http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-ajaxoptions-and-cache-options-added-beforeload-event](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8673)

[http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8673](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-ajaxoptions-and-cache-options-added-beforeload-event)